# help me find the minimum cost

Tags: inequality, optimization

an insurance company employs full and part-time staff, who work 40 and 20 hours per week respectively. Full-time staff are paid $\$800$ per-week and part-time-staff $\$320.$

In addition, it is company policy that the number of part-time staff should not exceed one-third of the number of full-time staff . If the number of worker-hours per week required to deal with the company's work is 900, how many workers of each type should be employed in order to complete the workload at minimum cost?

Comment: What is the information telling you, in terms of the parameters given? Try to translate the information into equations and or inequalities (constraints). Also, are you studying calculus? It would help us to help you if you add what context this question came from, and also add what preliminary work you've done on the problem. We're not too fond of simply churning out solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since a major component of "word problems" is translating the words and data into equations and inequalities, I'll help you translate the information to mathematics, and challenge you to be able to relate these equations and inequalities.

Let $f$ denote the number of full-time staff, and let $p$ denote the number of part-time staff.

Now, we need for the number of part-time employees to not exceed (be less than or equal to) $\frac 13$ the number of full-time employees. This gives us $$p \leq \frac 13 f \iff f \geq 3p.$$

We also need the number of worker-hours per week to be, minimally, $900$ hours, knowing that part-timers work $20$ hours per week, and full-timers work $40$ hours per week. This gives us $$20p + 40 f \geq 900$$

(Keep in mind, we would like an equality here, if the minimization of cost allows it, but the minimization of cost might entail slightly exceeding $900$ hours.)

The expression we then want to minimize is the labor cost for the insurance company, with labor cost $(C)$ given by: $$C = 320 p + 800 f$$

Comment: Let me know where you are in your studies, what tools you have available that might apply here, and whether or not you get stuck in working with the above constrains or "cost function" C.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Put

$$\begin{cases}x:=\text{no. of full-times employees}\\y:=\text{no. of part-times employees}\end{cases}$$

You need to minimize $\;f(x,y)=800x+320y\;$ with the constraints:

$$\begin{align*}y&\le\frac x3\\40x+20y&=900\\x,y&>0\end{align*}$$

Now draw the constraints on a $\;xy-$ plane and evaluate at the boundary and/or intersection points of the region you drew (why? This is a theorem) and choose the minimal value...

Comment: $900$ is worker-*hours*, not workers! So $x + y = 900$ is way off. We need $40x + 20 y = 900$ (or, rather, perhaps $40x + 20y \geq 900$).

Comment: Yauzaah! You are right, @amWhy...completely missed that one. Editing on its way and thanks.

Comment: You may not get optimum at integer intersections in this LP, though it isn't hard finding closest integer solutions from the graph by "sliding" the objective line down...

Answer (score 0):

A more "wordy" way:

With $x$ as number of full time workers and $y$ the number of part time workers, by looking at hourly rates it is evident you should try to maximise $y$ to get the minimum cost.

However $y \le \frac{x}3$, so the best possible is when we have this at equality, i.e. $40x + 20 \frac{x}3 = 900$ which gives $x \approx 19.29$.  As the number of workers has to be a whole number, we have to set $x = 20$ at least (note we cannot decrease $x$ and increase $y$), and then it is easy to find the $y$ which satisfies your weekly load requirements ...

ADDED:

Note that $(x, y)=(19\frac27,6\frac37)$ is the optimum we get.  Assuming we need whole number of workers, we have to decide whether to drop $x$ or increase $x$.  Dropping $x$ is clearly not feasible, as this means $y$ cannot be increased beyond $6$, and then the workload won't be satisfied.   So we have to increase $x$ by the barest minimum, $(x, y) =(20, 5)$ works.  Note further that increasing $x$ any further and hence decreasing $y$ is not in the direction of lowest cost (remember $x$ is costlier).

Comment: P.S. If you are studying integer programming, then formulating equations is probably what you should be doing rather than this.

Comment: Yes, much clearer now. I've deleted my earlier comments. ;-)